# How to change an objects properties right after a condition is met?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a button go from .disabled = true to .disabled = false. I am making a Yahtzee clone for fun, and you have to choose a score to take on your third roll, and then after that the button will be unlocked and you can roll again. Here's what I had, but it crashes. I wanted to make a while statement until a score is selected. ptsss is the amount of scores that have been selected. (i.e. third roll should equal 1 score entered)

```
if(rollcount == 3){
      while (ptsss * 3 < rollcount){
         document.getElementById("rollbutton").disabled = true;
         if (ptsss * 3 == rollcount){
            document.getElementById("rollbutton").disabled = false;
            break;
         }
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Hi.  First, you never should use any of the built-in `document.getElement...` methods multiple times for the same element.  It's a costly operation.  Instead, store it in a variable and access *that*: `let rollBtn = document.getElementById("rollbutton"); rollBtn.disabled = true; /* or */ rollBtn.disabled = false;`  Second, how is `ptsss` generated and incremented?  Do you ever actually reach a point where `ptsss * 3 >= rollcount`?  Because it looks like you're stuck in an infinite while-loop from what I can see here

Comment: @MajorProductions 1 is added to ptsss every time a score button is pressed. Therefore, when ptsss is equal to one after one score button has been pressed, it puts that and allows the user to continue because it is equal to the amount of rolls to get there (roll count). maybe I am missing something that will never let this be true

Comment: Actually you always enter an infinite loop if `ptsss * 3` is not equal to `rollcount`. JavaScript is single threaded - the value of `ptsss` cannot be changed by code somewhere else while this code (and `while` loop) is running. Try converting your logic to being event driven.

Comment: You should probably rethink your design.  Because this code snippet is using a loop to check a value and then toggle a button based on that value which doesn't make any kind of conceptual sense.  You only want to use a loop if you're doing some kind of repetition then and there.  So... maybe an outer loop with something like: `if(rollcount == 3) { if(ptsss * 3 < rollcount) { rollBtn.disabled = true; } else { rollBtn.disabled = false; }}` (adjusting formatting for new lines and proper indentation of course).  Because using a loop for this kind of check is overkill

Comment: Put another way: you probably *do* want some kind of loop for rolling dice.  You 100% *don't* want to make *another* loop simply to check a die's individual value.  You put that check in the main loop rather than making another one just for that task.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `while` loop and (possibly) rewrite the code as a function to enable/disable the roll button as required. E.G.

```
function checkRollButton( rollcount, ptsss) {
  if(rollcount == 3) {
    document.getElementById("rollbutton").disabled = ptsss != 1;
  }
}
```

Then call (or inline the code for) `checkRollbutton` in event handlers that update `rollcount` and/or `ptsss`.

---

- As commented, the value of `ptsss` cannot be changed by other code while the `while` loop is running, because JavaScript is single threaded.
- I've modified the statement that enables/disables the roll button according to my understanding of the design, please check it before use.

Answer (score 0):

Loops in JavaScript are not like loops in some other languages.

If the condition in the loop is not being modified within the loop itself, it won't be modified (unless possibly it's happening inside an asynchronous function).

Also you shouldn't constantly use the `getElement` in a loop anyways.

The way to achieve the general functionality of what a while loop is in other languages, in JavaScript, is to use an `interval`.

So based on that your updated code can look something like this (not sure where the first if statement is being called from so I took it out, also the nested if statement would have never been called because it only takes effect if it's condition is false, so I changed that as well):

```
var roll=document.getElementById("rollbutton")//make sure this is called after that element has loaded


 var inter=setInterval(function(){
        if (ptsss * 3 == rollcount){
            roll.disabled = false;
            clearInterval(inter)
            //Similar to break in while loop, can restart interval later after this
         }
        if (ptsss * 3 < rollcount){
         roll.disabled = true;
         
      }
    }
 },1000/30//30 FPS
);
```